# Memory use in SQL Server and C/C++ 

Tags: c++, c, sql-server-2008, file, memory

Is there a way to avoid writing to file, and keep a table in main memory?, using C/C++ and SQL Server 2008?

Comment: The question is not ridiculous, it makes no sense. Sql server files are binary. What chunking? Sql does ndeal with that itself.

Comment: I down voted this question simply becuase I just wasted a minute of my life trying to fathom "what on Earth is he talking about"... only to discovert that it's 42. A lot more information about the problem, the context, and your ACTUAL underlying requirments would go a LONG way to getting your question answered. How To Ask Good Questions... google it yourself.

Comment: @darkcminor--please reformulate the question. I'm with @TomTom and @corlettk on this--hard to understand what you are asking. Imagine yourself in our shoes--how would you answer something like this. Remember, we know nothing about your problem domain and have 2 seconds to look over the question to even decide whether we are going to consider helping you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean whether there is an in-memory version of the SQL Server, like TimesTen for Oracle the answer is no. If you mean a 'little' database that you can add to your App see MS SQL Compact Server.

If you mean using memory mapped files instead of a database, see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile(VS.100).aspx

Otherwise, please be more specific in your question!

hth

Mario